# Writing data to Azure Iot hub device

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am currently doing a POC where I would like to know if this is possible using Azure Services. I get certain data from Iot hub in my Event hub which triggers a logic app, and based on the message received from Event hub, My logic app would send a message to IoT Edge device. i would like to know if it is possible to send message to IoT hub device from logic app? and if yes how can we do that?

I am more looking Yes or No answer to my question and If I get the services to be used to achieve this.. It will be great

Comment: Can you illustrate what you are trying to achieve or add a flow diagram of the input, output on each service you want to use on Azure? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Logic Apps have an Event Hub connector that you can use to start your app when a message comes in.

To send a message to your Azure IoT Edge device from a logic app, you could use [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/modules/invoke-method?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). It allows you to send a direct method to a specific module on the device. The device needs to be online for it to receive the message, otherwise, the REST call will result in an error.

*The challenge* is that you will need to get a valid security token to complete this call, you could certainly add this to your app as a variable, but you shouldn't. You also run the risk of exposing this secret value in your run history. You could write an Azure Function to generate this security token and retrieve it with the Logic App. At this point you're writing code anyway, the problem you're trying to solve with a Logic App would be a better fit for an Azure Function.

Comment: its encouraging to hear that this is possible, now I am going to try out . Sending message to IoT device. Do you have any documentation you can refer me here. What kind of REST protocol we are talking here, klets say i keep The security token for now as hardcoded. its just a demo, so no risk involved.

Comment: oh sorry, you already gave me the link to REST api, where do i pass the security token?

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) should give you an overview of everything needed for the REST API.

Comment: One question here, we are here talking about Iot Edge devices or Iot Devices? These REST apis are for what kind of devices. Can you please confirm

Comment: There is an API for both. The one I linked you can be used for Azure IoT Edge devices.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between two?

Comment: and we generate the SAS token for running the api , I hope this is the way to do it

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/iotdev/azure-iot-toolkit-1-1-0-for-vs-code-released-welcome-page-generate-sas-token-deploy-edge-device-at-scale-and-more/#generate-sas-token

Comment: I'm sorry, this is starting to go far beyond the scope of your original question. I can answer all your follow-up questions, but at this point, you might want to check out the docs or [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/browse/?expanded=azure&products=azure-iot). I don't want to come off as rude, but both here and on Microsoft Q&A there are a lot of people helping out, it would be helpful if you did some research before continuing.

Comment: I did the following thing but gets Unauthorized error:

I created an IoT Edge Device and created the SAS token by the link above and also by following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node#security-token-structure
Then I ran the GET method API to get my twin details , in Header I passed Authorization with value as the token generated from the above link and I get error as IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized

Comment: So finally figured out, It was issue with SaS token and for some reason the code used for generating SAS token was not working, but then I tried the Azure CLI way and used the SAS token generated from there and it worked. I used this link to get my SAS token https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-generate-sas-token
Also it is important to understand the SAS token generated here is at IoT hub level with a policy name and not at the device level.

Comment: Happy you found it, good luck with the Poc! Thanks for linking the docs.